# Google sheets - on clicking a tab/sheet trigger a action

Tags: google-sheets

In Google sheets, I have multiple sheets/tab in one spreadsheet file.  I want to trigger a action when I switch from one tab to another i.e. when I click on the tab name / sheet name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same solution. The only answer I've come up with is to hide all sheets but one and force the user to click a button to select a sheet to be unhidden, afterwhich the current sheet is hidden.